# get only the selected column from the join table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this reference code below, first the line 1 will get

```
$aa = users_details::select(array('id', 'user_id'))->where('id', '=', $request->id)->first(); //first line
$bb = User::select(array('user_id'))->where('user_id', '=', $aa->id)->with('user_details')->first(); //second line
```

the first line returns 13 which is correct while the second line returns 'null' which it should not because there's actually a record that has a user_id of '13'. Any ideas, help please?

and also is there a way I could select only selected columns in this join table (Eloquent relationship hasOne)

```
$bb = User::select(array('user_id'))->where('user_id', '=', $aa->id)->with('user_details')->first();
```

I dont know if

> select(array('user_id'))

is the right one to select only selected columns from the join table. Any ideas, help, please?

Comment: Not very familiar with laravel but try `where('user_id', '=', $aa)`

Answer (score 1):

First Question:

```
$bb = User::select(array('user_id'))->where('user_id', '=', $aa->id)->with('user_details')->first();
```

Do you have `user_id` column in users (or anywhere `User` Model refers to) table? Do you have `user_details` method in User model?

Second Question:

You can select as

```
User::select('user_id', 'username', 'sex')
```

If you have same column name in the joined table, then you can select as

```
User::select('users.user_id as a', 'users.username', 'users.sex', 'user_details.user_id as b')
```

**UPDATE:**

> How can I select only selected column from the 'user_details' when
>   both is joining togehter?

```
User::select('users.user_id as user_id', 'users.username', 'users.sex', 'user_details.user_id as user_details_id')->join('user_details','user_details.user_id','=', 'users.id' )->where('users.id', '=', $aa->id)->first();
```

To select the columns from the joined table, just prefix the column name with table name such as `user_details.user_id`.

Comment: first question answer is yes, the primary column of 'users' table is 'user_id' and the foreign key of the 'user_table' is the 'user_id' column where it refers to the 'user_id' column of the 'users' table. How can I select only selected column from the 'user_details' when both is joining togehter? any ideas?